# Test the function inside click handler - Jest, React testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a button click handler in which I call another function. I need to test the function call inside of the handler:

**SomeComponent**

```
...
const handler = () => {
  someFunction();
}
...
<button data-testId="button" onClick={handler}>Click Me</button>
```

**test**

```
describe('Button click', () => {
  it('button click', async () => {
    render(<SomeComponent />);

    const button = await screen.findByTestId('button');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    // some silly test case just for example
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

While doing this, it covers the handler but not the inner function itself:

```
const handler = () => { <<<<<<< covered
  someFunction();       <<<<<<< UNCOVERED
}.                      <<<<<<< covered
```

The main question here is how can I test the inner function call? If I need to mock it, how should I do it, because the mocked function will not test the actual one?

**UPDATE**

Also, my someFunction doesn't change anything in the scope of this component, so I can't catch it by comparing the inner state or document change.

SomeFunction is coming from another file and I tested it separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where `someFunction` is defined. If it's a property given to `<SomeComponent />` then you could do something like this:

```js
describe('Button click', () => {
  it('button click', async () => {
    const someFunction = jest.fn();
    render(<SomeComponent someFunction={someFunction} />);

    const button = await screen.findByTestId('button');
    fireEvent.click(button);

    // if there are some precise arguments given to `someFunction` maybe 
    // use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` instead
    expect(someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But if it's defined in a separate hook then you should mock this hook. For instance here let's assume there a `useSomeFunction` that directly returns this `someFunction`:

```js
import { useSomeFunction  } from '../path/to/useSomeFunction';

jest.mock('../path/to/useSomeFunction', () => ({
  useSomeFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Button click', () => {
  it('button click', async () => {
    const mockSomeFunction = jest.fn();
    useSomeFunction.mockImplementation(() => mockSomeFunction);
    render(<SomeComponent />);

    const button = await screen.findByTestId('button');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    // if there are some precise arguments given to `someFunction` maybe 
    // use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` instead
    expect(mockSomeFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And if it's simply a function defined elsewhere you could adapt the example I gave with hook mocking:

```js
import { someFunction } from '../path/to/util';

jest.mock('../path/to/util', () => ({
  someFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Button click', () => {
  it('button click', async () => {

    render(<SomeComponent />);

    const button = await screen.findByTestId('button');
    fireEvent.click(button);

    // if there are some precise arguments given to `someFunction` maybe 
    // use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` instead
    expect(someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case, I just imported it from another file, and I tested this function separately.

Comment: So did it work or still looking for answers? @RobertHovhannisyan

Comment: Nah, still looking for the answer :/

Comment: I've added a third case that looks like your use case

Comment: Moment, let me try it out

Comment: Please note that if your component is using other parts from `../path/to/util` and you don't want to mock everything, maybe simply do:  `jest.mock('../path/to/util', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../path/to/util'),  someFunction: jest.fn() }));`
```

Answer (score 0):

> `someFunction()` needs to generate some side effects to your app. You
> can test those side effects. For instance if `someFunction()` was
> incrementing a count state value you could test for that in your
> component to check if count was incremented when button was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the option, but I forgot to mention that I can't measure any state change, because it doesn't give any side effects

Comment: What exactly is `someFunction()` doing in your application ?

Comment: It creates a blob