# How to test a function that is defined within the component

Tags: typescript, testing, ts-jest

I am attempting to test that a function within my component is called onClick, however every instance I'm seeing online is showing examples of exporting the function or defining the function outside the component so it can be mocked, however this is not my case.

```
const DocumentCard = ({ docInfo }: Props) => {
  const myFunction = async (id: string) => {
    //my logic in here
  }

  const handleOpen = () => {
    //my logic here
  }
  return (
    <Box>
      <CardMedia
        data-testid="documentId"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('i get here')
          handleOpen()
          if (documentInfo && documentInfo.objectId)
            console.log('do i ever get here???')
          myFunction(documentInfo.objectId)
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default DocumentCard
```

I have seen pages like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167057/test-the-function-inside-click-handler-jest-react-testing-library) giving examples of testing functions, but not ones inside the component. I have attempted to use jest.spyOn every time I get the error that it cannot find the element to spy on, I have also used `jest.fn` to try to simulate the method being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, and you shouldn't. It's *entirely* internal to the component and not possible to even export a reference that you could call from a test.

Ask yourself: "Why does this function exist? What is it expected to do?"

Then your test should use your whole component, and assert that whatever that function does got done, but you should not test that function directly.